# GCN with Opacus (Applying differential privacy to GCNs)

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to wrap a GNC with Opacus and I'm running into this error:

> File "c:\Users\me\Desktop\github\opacus_graph\tds.py", line 124, in
> loss.backward()File
> "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch_tensor.py",
> line 487, in backwardtorch.autograd.backward(File
> "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\autograd_init_.py",
> line 200, in backwardVariable._execution_engine.run_backward(  # Calls
> into the C++ engine to run the backward passFile
> "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py",
> line 69, in callreturn self.hook(module, *args, **kwargs)File
> "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\opacus\grad_sample\grad_sample_module.py",
> line 342, in capture_backprops_hookgrad_samples =
> grad_sampler_fn(module, activations, backprops)File
> "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\opacus\grad_sample\functorch.py",
> line 62, in ft_compute_per_sample_gradientper_sample_grads =
> layer.ft_compute_sample_grad(File
> "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch_functorch\vmap.py",
> line 426, in wrappedbatch_size, flat_in_dims, flat_args, args_spec =
> _process_batched_inputs(in_dims, args, func)File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch_functorch\vmap.py",
> line 119, in _process_batched_inputsreturn
> _validate_and_get_batch_size(flat_in_dims, flat_args), flat_in_dims, flat_args, args_specFile
> "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch_functorch\vmap.py",
> line 52, in _validate_and_get_batch_sizeraise ValueError(ValueError:
> vmap: Expected all tensors to have the same size in the mapped
> dimension, got sizes [16, 7] for the mapped dimension

My train is defined as this:

```
for epoch in range(10):
    print("make functional params: \n\n", model)
    for batch in data_loader:
        print("batch ", batch)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        out = model(batch)
        out.to(device)
        loss = F.nll_loss(out, batch.y)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

It's getting to loss.backward() but crashing upon using .backward()

It's worth noting that as long as I don't use

```
model, optimizer, train_loader = privacy_engine.make_private_with_epsilon(
    module = model,
    optimizer=optimizer,
    data_loader=data_loader,
    epochs=10,
    target_epsilon=5,
    target_delta=0.0001,
    max_grad_norm=122,
    poisson_sampling=False,
    batch_first=False # tensor is shape [K, batch_size, ...], if false: [batch_size, ...]
)
```

the code will train, however wrapping it with Opacus is leading to these errors

Thanks!